# Converting base64 value to number

Tags: c#, base64

I am receiving data regarding vehicle speeds.  I have no control over the input format, but I do need to use the data.

The data is sent to me as Base64 encoded values.  Apparently, the data started out as a number in little endian format.  Currently, my code is this:

```
public int b64ToInt(string Input){

    byte[] Output = Convert.FromBase64String(Input);
    Array.Reverse(Output);
    if (Output.Length == 1)
    {
        return (int)Output[0];
    }
    else if (Output.Length == 2)
    {
        return (int)BitConverter.ToInt16(Output, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(Output, 0);
    }
}
```

This works for most values I receive, but not all.  By the way, to convert this value to MPH, I need to divide by 1150.78.

The following value works:  AAB6Qg==  Converts to 27.19720537374 MPH.

The following value does not work:  **AA09**  Apparently, the length of the Output array is 3 bytes and I don't know how to handle this situation.

The error message I get is: "Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length."

Comment: It sounds like you need to find out a lot more about what the data format is really meant to be.

Comment: I agree, but the company that I am getting this data from is not very helpful.  I feel stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: Do you know what the numeric value associated with AA09 is supposed to be?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: You should check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` before reversing your array, btw. On Windows I believe `BitConverter` is *already* little-endian.

Comment: @GMastros That's going to make it pretty much impossible to answer your question, unfortunately.  I mean, you could pad your byte array in order to pass it to `BitConverter`, but without being able to verify the results there would be no way of knowing which side to pad it on, or even whether that's the correct approach at all.

Comment: I may have confused the big endian/little endian stuff.  However, I know I MUST reverse the order of bytes.

Comment: **AA09** in base64 is only 3 bytes (24 bits), which is why `ToInt32` expects another byte. Perhaps you could give some more context on the data you are receiving and/or explain your assumptions: e.g. how you can know/verify the value **AAB6Qg==** is meant to = 27.197, where you got 1150.78 from and/or provide a snippet of some other input values you're getting.

Comment: The string "AAB6Qg==", when decoded, results in `{ 00, 00, 7A, 42 }`. That's the big-endian number 0x00007A42, or 31,298. The number is being sent to you as big-endian and you're converting it to little-endian.

Comment: Apparently, the data is captured from the device in knots.  It is then multiplied by 1000, converted to base64, and then sent to me.  After converting back to a number, I need to divide by 1000 and multiple by 1.15078 which converts knots to MPH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the number yourself, from the decoded bytes. That is, rather than `BitConverter.ToInt16` or `BitConverter.ToInt32`, do the following. (Note that I don't reverse the array.)

```
byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
Console.WriteLine(output.Length);
int rslt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; ++i)
{
    rslt <<= 8;
    rslt += output[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(rslt);
Console.WriteLine((double)rslt / 1150.78);
```

Given an input string of "AAB6Qg==", that produces 27.1972053737465. "AA09" produces 2.94495907123864.

What I'm doing here is just fitting those four bytes into a 32-bit integer. The `<<= 8` means "shift left 8 bits". The effect is that bytes are shifted one position to the left each time through the loop.

So, given the array `{ 00, 00, 7A, 42 }`, `rslt` starts at 0. The result stays at 0 until we get to the 3rd byte. Then:

```
rslt += output[2];  // rslt = 0x0000007A
// next time through the loop
rslt <<= 8          // rslt = 0x00007A00
rslt += output[3];  // rslt = 0x00007A42
```

Comment: Can you explain this line:  rslt <<= 8;  I don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: This looks like its probably the right thing to do (in essence padding the three bytes to four with a 0 most significant byte).

Comment: `<<` is a shift which effectively means multiplying by `2^8` in this case and then <<= means do that and assign back to `rslt` (similar to +=). (I'm assuming you know how bytes related to integer values?)

Comment: Thanks @Chris I do understand how bytes relate to integer values.  Basically, <<= 8 is shifting the bits to the left 8 times.

Comment: Thank you Jim.  I have confirmed that this is working properly.  I especially appreciate the explanation regarding the bit shifting.